# jest react18: Expected key descriptor but found "" in ""

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest

- Our test cases were working in react 16 and we recently updated to react 18 and test cases started to fail. Below is the sample code where searchComp is a variable assigned to input, And in input we type and filter the table

---

```
const Wrapper = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <TestComponent testId={'table-view'} />
  </Provider>
);
it('Recently Added Search : test', async () => {
    await render(<Wrapper />);
    await waitFor(
      async () => {
        store.dispatch(setTabIndex(1));
        const searchComp = screen.getByTestId('recent-search-input');
        userEvent.type(searchComp, 'ABC');

        const table = await screen.getByRole('recentTable');
        expect(table).toHaveAttribute('aria-colcount', '4');
        expect(table).toHaveAttribute('aria-rowcount', '0');
      },
      { timeout: 5000 }
    );
  });
```

- error is as follows

> Expected key descriptor but found "" in "" See
> https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/keyboard for more
> information about how userEvent parses your input.
>
> at assertDescriptor
> (node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/cjs/utils/keyDef/readNextDescriptor.js:77:15) at readPrintableChar
> (node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/cjs/utils/keyDef/readNextDescriptor.js:33:5)
> at Object.readNextDescriptor
> (node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/cjs/utils/keyDef/readNextDescriptor.js:28:26) at Object.parseKeyDef
> (node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/cjs/keyboard/parseKeyDef.js:26:125)
> at Object.keyboard
> (node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/cjs/keyboard/index.js:17:33) at Object.type
> (node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/cjs/utility/type.js:26:16)
> at Object.asyncWrapper
> (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:73:22)

-I have tried by adding as below and it still not work. Please suggest

```
await userEvent.type(searchComp, 'ABC');
```

Comment: What is `searchComp` when this code executes? Probably time to set a breakpoint (e.g. `debugger`) and step through here.

Comment: searchComp is a variable assigned to input. And in input we type and filter the table

Comment: I'm suggesting you check it for sure.

Comment: This probably requires upgrading @testing-library/react and @testing-library/user-event